# SQL Query between condition only start position given

Tags: sql

I have a table student with fields sno , name etc. Given a sno i want to list all records after that number till the end. ie i want to get all records between 10(example) till the end. Please help

Comment: There you go!: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/
We are here to help with questions, issues, problems not to do the work for you. Do something, show us some of your work, your research and where you are stuck. In layman terms - effort.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: i wanted to loop through a set of records inorder to merge where the start number was determined from another condition .

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE sno >= 10
```

In case you want to pass a variable, just replace with a variable

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE sno >= @sno
```

I assume `@sno` is defined somewhere in your code

Comment: isn't it should be `> 10`... OP says **i want to list all records** ***after*** **that number**

Comment: @Fahim Parkar, well, OP used the word between. In sql, between also include "=". Anyway, that's not a big deal, sure he would know how to adjust to what he wants

Answer (score 0):

As simple as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE sno > 10
            ^^ here you will have your serial number...
```

But I don't understand why you want to play with serial number. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Fahim Parkar i have a table with fields sNo etc but some sNos are missing ie i have 1,2 3,4,5 then 7,8,9 etc . i want it to become 1,2,3, 4, 5, 6 ie record with sNo 7 gets the new value 6 and so on... the data is in ms access , so trying for a way to solve it as a query without any other programming language.

Comment: Like this i have 100 differnt tables , so after numbering them in sequence i want to merge them.